# Convert string to int and get the number of characters consumed in C++ with stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am new to C++ (coming from a C# background) and am trying to learn how to convert a string to an int.

I got it working by using a `stringstream` and outputting it into a `double`, like so:

```
const char* inputIndex = "5+2";
double number = 0;
stringstream ss(inputIndex);
ss >> number;
// number = 5
```

This works great. The problem I'm having is that the strings I'm parsing *start* with a number, but may have other, not digit characters after the digits (e.g. "5+2", "9-(3+2)", etc). The `stringstream` parses the digits at the beginning and stops when it encounters a non-digit, like I need it to.

The problem comes when I want to know how many characters were used to parse into the number. For example, if I parse `25+2`, I want to know that two characters were used to parse `25`, so that I can advance the string pointer.

So far, I got it working by clearing the `stringstream`, inputting the parsed number back into it, and reading the length of the resulting string:

```
ss.str("");
ss << number;

inputIndex += ss.str().length();
```

While this does work, it seems really hacky to me (though that might just be because I'm coming from something like C#), and I have a feeling that might cause a memory leak because the `str()` creates a copy of the string.

Is there any other way to do this, or should I stick with what I have?

Thanks.

Comment: Charles has the answer you asked for. More generally, when you use streams you tend to put all your input in them so you don't need to return to the `const char*` and shuffle it along by the number of characters you've just converted to a number. Your idea about deriving the length from streaming out won't work in general, as there can be distinct-length representations of the same number (e.g. "+25", "25", "25.00", "0x19").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::stringstream::tellg()` to find out the current get position in the input stream.  Store this value in a variable before you extract from the stream.  Then get the position again *after* you extract from the stream.  The difference between these two values is the number of characters extracted.

```
double x = 3435;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << x;

double y;
std::streampos pos = ss.tellg();
ss >> y;
std::cout << (ss.tellg() - pos) << " characters extracted" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked great! I think I may ultimately go with Tony's suggestion in the comments above, though.

Answer (score 1):

The solution above using tellg() will fail on modern compilers (such as gcc-4.6).

The reason for this is that tellg() really shows the position of the cursor, which is now out of scope.  See eg "[file stream tellg/tellp and gcc-4.6 is this a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552876/file-stream-tellg-tellp-and-gcc-4-6-is-this-a-bug)"

Therefore you need to also test for eof() (meaning the entire input was consumed).