# file stream tellg/tellp and gcc-4.6 is this a bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, iostream

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{   
    std::remove("test.txt");
    std::fstream f("test.txt",std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);
    std::cout << f.good() << std::endl;
    f<<"test"<< std::flush;
    std::cout << f.tellg() << " " << f.tellp() << std::endl;
    f.seekg(0);
    std::string s;
    f>>s;
    std::cout << f.tellg() << " " << f.tellp() << std::endl;
}
```

Gives following output in gcc-4.4.5

```
1
4 4
4 4
```

i.e. both tellg and tellp returned expected stream position 4.

While gcc-4.6.0

Gives:

```
1
4 4
-1 4
```

Where can I find a reference to tell:

1. 1st case is correct (bug in gcc-4.6)
2. 2nd case is correct (bug in gcc < gcc-4.6)
3. Both case are correct the behavior is undefined

Comment: What's going on with `std::remove`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it is not a bug, even it seems that it is required behavior:

According to C++ 2003 standard:

- tellg(): (27.6.1.3)

  > After constructing a sentry object, if fail() != false, returns pos_type(-1) to indicate failure. Otherwise, returns rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, cur, in).
- sentry (27.6.1.1.2):

  > if noskipws is zero and is.flags() & ios_base::skipws is nonzero, the func-
  >   tion extracts and discards each character as long as the next available input character c is a whitespace character. If is.rdbuf()->sbumpc() or is.rdbuf()->sgetc() returns traits::eof(), the function calls setstate(failbit | eofbit) (which may throw ios_base::failure).

So basically

- tellg() creates sentry object:
- sentry extracts white space characters and should set failbit after getting to eof.
- tellg() sees failbit should return eof() (-1)

So gcc-4.6 seems to behave correctly...

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the difference. However, it is *not* a difference of the compiler, it is not a difference of the standard library headers, it is a difference of the linked shared library.

It doesn't depend on the gcc version. It doesn't depend on architecture:

```
t44:       ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
t45:       ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
t46:       ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
```

The real difference seems to be

- meerkat: libstdc++6 4.5.1-7ubuntu2
- natty: libstdc++6 4.6.0-3~ppa1 (from [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test))

### On ubuntu meerkat

```
$ uname -a
Linux natty 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
$ for a in t4?; do ./$a; done
1
4 4
4 4
1
4 4
4 4
1
4 4
4 4
```

### On ubuntu natty

```
Linux natty 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
sehe@natty:/mnt/jail/home/sehe$ for a in t4?; do ./$a; done
1
4 4
-1 4
1
4 4
-1 4
1
4 4
-1 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, separate from the version analysis, which I'll leave for good measure, here is the answer:

## PR/26211

I'll try to find source, but this thread discusses whether the documentation needs to be updated due to this change. It is therefore, a documented change :)

**Edit** Only found this: [libstdc++/26211 (again) + N3168](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/72121/)

From this page: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2011-04/msg00026.html

> Hey, all.
>
> I recently started using gcc-4.6.0 and it seems that the behaviour of
>   std::istream::tellg() has changed when (just) the eofbit is set.  I
>   managed to track this down to PR/26211, and I'm not debating the
>   changes.
>
> It took me a while to figure out what was wrong because the doxygen
>   for tellg() says:
>
> ```
> If fail() is not false, returns pos_type(-1) to indicate
> failure. Otherwise returns rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0,cur,in).
> ```
>
> That's almost word for word what Langer and Kreft says, so I'm
>   presuming DR60's change to 27.6.1.3 paragraph 37 has lead to this
>   change in libstdc++ behaviour.
>
> Should the libstdc++ doxygen be updated to say something about the
>   fact that calling `tellg()`when `eof()` will also return `pos_type(-1)`
>   (because of the fact that it constructs a sentry)?  Are there other
>   functions that also should have updated documentation as a result of
>   DR60?

Comment: But `eof()` is not part of `fail()`. There are three bits in the state, `eofbit`, `badbit`, and `failbit`. `fail()` only reports if any of the last two are set. (27.5.5.4/9 of the FDIS)

Comment: @Bo: That's exactly the point, I think. Why do you start with `but`? Also, note I didn't write that text, it was from the GNU devs mailing list

Comment: I used 'but' because I don't see how this has changed. I believe that tellp and tellg should call the same `fseekpos` function from the underlying C library, unless Paolo Carlini has found something I have missed.

Comment: The question is if it is a bug and seems to be a bug, can I found anything in the standard to relate so I can open a bug?

Comment: The linked resources strongly suggest that the old behaviour was a bug. I haven't found a matching specification. I suppose you could find it. You could of course do the pragmatic thing and check ecplicitely for the eof condition, instead of relying on behaviour that you admit you can't find the specification for ;)