# Should I expect different behavior with fstream exception handling between CentOS6 and CentOS7?

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, centos, fstream

I am reading data from file with an fstream object, while using exception handling. Because of how the logic is implemented, the code will execute a tellg() on the fstream **after** a fstream::failure exception is thrown when the end-of-file is hit. This execution flow is not necessarily intentional, but it hasn't caused any problems when running on Windows (MSVS 2010) or CentOS6. But, when running on CentOS7, I get a core dump. If I add a call to clear() the fstream prior to the tellg(), all is good.

There error that is thrown is:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'
>   what():  basic_ios::clear

Can someone provide insight as to whether this change in behavior is expected, or not?

The applicable versions of gcc and libstdc++ are:

For CentOS6:

- gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC)
- /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13

For CentOS7:

- gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC)
- /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19

A code sample that exercises the issue follows:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   fstream in;
   in.exceptions(ifstream::failbit);

   cout << "Before open" << endl;
   in.open("in.txt", ios::in);
   cout << "After open" << endl;

   try
   {
      string s;
      while ( 1 )
      {
         getline(in, s);
         cout << s << endl;
      }
   }
   catch(fstream::failure e)
   {
      cout << "EOF Exception." << endl;
   }
   catch(...)
   {
      cout << "Unhandled Exception." << endl;
   }

   // --- uncomment this to make it work ---  in.clear();
   in.tellg();

   return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552876/file-stream-tellg-tellp-and-gcc-4-6-is-this-a-bug).

Comment: @n.m. ah yes, could be ... but none of the answers there links to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26211 or http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#419

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [PR 26211](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26211) GCC 4.6.0 implements the resolution of [DR 419](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#419), so the new behaviour is intentional.

There was a defect in the standard, which was fixed, and so GCC's library was changed to match the new specification in the standard.